# Deploying django with Nginx

Tags: apache-http-server, django

I would like to know has anyone been successful to run django on nginx? I have several django apps running on Apache2 on suse 11.4 and i would like to migrate them to nginx. Are there any modules that django requires in order to successfully run on nginx.

Comment: it is really good question.

Answer (score 3):

On of our setups runs a Django/NginX/gunicorn setup, which to be honnest runs very well. We have more than 30k users per day. I used the following tutorial:
http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options. Just Googling `Django nginx` will give you a good idea how people handle their Django sites. The easiest is to use Django's built-in FastCGI server. The most popular *seems* to be uWSGI (I constantly see people raving on about it). I use FastCGI and it works just fine for me.

But this should give you an idea of where to start.

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ServerArrangements#nginx

The two links near the top of this section should help explain more.

Answer (score 0):

nginx is very flexible and very nice when you use it with uwsgi so i think your best choice is uwsgi and nginx for serving Django, [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) is the for ubuntu setup tutorial and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7) is for CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

you can use nginx + uwsgi + django, This tutorial is here: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html?